# Why is this struct initialized with data already in a field?

Tags: c++, c, struct, undefined-behavior, arrays

I'm using a library written in *C*, with my own program that's in *C++*. They *typedef* a struct like this:

```
typedef struct tagCtxt
{
    char     iadl1[50+1];
    char     iadl2[50+1];
    char     iprurb[28+1];
    char     iadl3[50+1];
} PARM;
```

In one of my methods, I construct it and immediately print the value of one of the fields:

```
PARM parm1;
cout << "'" << parm1.iadl3 << "'" << endl;
```

As expected, it's blank/empty:

```
''
```

Now I do this, creating `parm2`:

```
PARM parm1, parm2;
cout << "'" << parm1.iadl3 << "'\t'" << parm2.iadl3 << "'" endl;
```

Then I get this:

```
''    'x��'
```

The output of the second one varies. Sometimes it looks like `XŰ` or `8ư` or `�ǰ` or `ǰ`, etc.

This line appears to fix the symptoms:

```
memset(&parm2.iadl3, 0, sizeof(parm2.iadl3));
```

But what is the problem? Why is the char array non-empty for the second one, but not for the first?

Remember, my program is compiled as *C++* but the header file I'm using that defines the type is in *C*. Does that make a difference? I'm including the header file like so:

```
extern "C"
{
    #include "parm.h"
}
```

Comment: It's UB to access those uninitialized fields. And you don't need `memset`, just use `PARM parm1 = {};`. This will value(zero)-initialize the members.

Comment: Bingo. That does the trick. (Why did I not know this? Hm.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), the initial value of an *automatic variable* is indeterminate, you need to initialize variables before you use them.

The [C99 draft standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) in section `6.2.4` *Storage durations of objects* says after covering *static variables* says (*emphasis mine*):

> For such an object that does not have a variable length array type, its lifetime extends
>   from entry into the block with which it is associated until execution of that block ends in
>   any way. [...] **The initial value of the object is indeterminate**. [...]

and the definition of *indeterminate value* is as follows:

> either an unspecified value or a trap representation

The [C++ draft standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf) section `8.5` *Initializers* paragraph *12* says (*emphasis mine*):

> If no initializer is specified for an object, the object is default-initialized; if no initialization is performed, **an object with automatic or dynamic storage duration has indeterminate value**. [ Note: Objects with static or thread storage duration are zero-initialized, see 3.6.2. —end note ]

A good place to get started in understanding some forms of *undefined behavior* is the [Deep C](http://www.slideshare.net/olvemaudal/deep-c) slides.

Comment: Okay. Can you explain why `parm1` is always blank, and, though I failed to mention, nearly all the other fields in the struct are also blank, when constructed, but `parm2` has these problems?

Comment: @Matt it is indeterminate, the compiler is allowed to do what ever it wants.

Comment: So it's by chance that after thousands of runs and dozens of compiles, it's still blank?

Comment: @Matt ofcourse. And chances are the program behaves exactly the same each run, if the exact same code and execution paths are taken. But it might, or it might not just take a small change to alter what you see.

Comment: @Matt It's pointless speculating why you're observing a certain behavior from code that exhibits UB.

Comment: @Matt If you are compiling in debug mode, the runtime could initialize the memory used by the program to help debugging (Thats what the windows heap implementation does, for example).

Comment: Interesting! Over thousands of iterations in a loop, seeing the behavior, I noticed patterns in the character codes that were being output. This makes a lot more sense now.

Comment: @Matt note that *indeterminated* does not mean *random*, it means *"We are not sure about what you would see"*. Also *undefined behaviour* means *"We don't guarantee the behaviour of that thing"* not *"If you do that it will crash"*

Comment: I get that. Thank you.

Comment: @Praetorian: The behavior is only undefined by the C or C++ standard, depending on which language is being used. However, the behavior is a consequence of many things: A specific C implementation, specific run-time libraries, the loader version, the operating system, and the hardware, all of which have (or should have) specifications. Many instances of behavior that is undefined by the language standard are defined by other things, and learning about why certain things happen even though they are not defined by the language standard can be educational about how other aspects of computers work.

Comment: @EricPostpischil indeed that is why I added the deep C slides as well, although a lot of people on SO really dislike when people try to explain UB. I guess mostly b/c there are so many variables you can't possibly cover them all and the OP does not usually provide enough info for a precise answer wrt that.

Comment: @Eric Ok, and how is any of that relevant here? Agreed, an implementation can choose to define behavior of code that the standard leaves undefined; but that is clearly not the case here, since the OP is observing different bit patterns depending on what struct instance/field he accesses. He was looking for an explanation of that specific behavior, and the answer is that there is no explanation other than it being some random bit patterns.

Comment: @Praetorian: It is relevant because a person asked a question about why things were as they were observed to be, and stating that there is no point in asking because the C or C++ standard does not specify it does not answer their question. Answering their question gives a person information that can be used to debug problems in the future. Even simply understanding that data was not initialized, rather than “these values appeared by magic because behavior is undefined”, can help people understand how the limits of a language standard translate to specific effects in various implementations.

Answer (score 2):

*"As expected, it's blank/empty:*" No, thats not expected. C++ dones not initialize the value of a  variable (Except its data type provides a constructor which does the job, or is a thing with static storage duration).

As Shafik said, reading the uninitialized data has undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't matter with the C/C++ thing.

In general, memory which you havn't set explicitly (like that `memset` operation u did) contains undefined values.

It's not 'expected' to be 0's.

Answer (score 1):

C and C++ provides no guarantee regarding values of local variables. They have a garbage values, depending on what is at that memory adress in the moment of allocation. In order to use them, you must initialize them with a value.

This is not true for global variables. They are initialized with 0 by default.

Answer (score 1):

```
char     iadl1[50+1];
```

Will reserve you a block of memory that are large enough to store 51 characters

However, it doesn't guarantee you that that block of memory is all empty, it just happens to be empty in your case. In general, use memset to initialize your arrays before accessing it would be the best way to do.

```
memset( iadl1, '\0', sizeof(char)*51);
```

Answer (score 1):

Only static variables have values pre-initialized.  Variables that are created on the stack (i.e. local variables) have garbage values, and thus should not be used before initializing.

Answer (score 0):

one way is to define a construct function to initialize the params

```
typedef struct tagCtxt
{
    tagCtxt()
    {
     memset( iadl1, '\0', sizeof(char)*51);
     memset( iadl2, '\0', sizeof(char)*51);
     memset( iprurb, '\0', sizeof(char)*29);
     memset( iadl3, '\0', sizeof(char)*51);
    }
    char     iadl1[50+1];
    char     iadl2[50+1];
    char     iprurb[28+1];
    char     iadl3[50+1];
} PARM;
```